# How to I change the domain value for handl cookies in WordPress and PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, utm-tracking

I am trying to change the domain value for `handl_url`, `handl_original_ref`, `handl_landing_page`, and `handl_ip` cookies on a WordPress website. I would like to do it via PHP, but if there is another way I open to knowing about it. Currently the domain is `.examplesite.com` and I need to remove the `.` so that it will be just `examplesite.com`. I have tried defining `COOKIE_DOMAIN` in `wp_config.php` and it does not work. Any insight or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to this WordPress plugin https://www.utmgrabber.com/ and you need to purchase the paid plugin to edit the domain value https://docs.utmgrabber.com/books/102-getting-started-for-handl-utm-grabber-v3/page/setting-domain-name